# Get elements from a json dictionary with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i have a following json that i want to read with Python and save table_name and column_filter in a variable in each iteration.
My json is like:

```
import json
dict_config = json.loads('''
    {
        "normal" : [
            {
                "table_name": "TABLE1",
                "column_filter": "TIME_TS"
            },
            {
                "table_name": "TABLE2",
                "column_filter": "TIME_DATE_TS"
            }
        ],
        "normal2" : [
            {
                "table_name": "TABLE3",
                "column_filter": "SOMETHING_TS"
            },
            {
                "table_name": "TABLE4",
                "column_filter": "DOCUMENT_TS"
            }
        ]
    }
''')

for each in dict_config.keys():
    for xx in dict_config[each]
        ...
        table_name=...
        column_filter=.....
```

How can i easily store value for of table_name and column_filter in normal,normal2,... element?
So in each iteration i want to get table_name & column_filter

Comment: what should be your final output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct, just index properly

```py
for each in dict_config:
    for xx in dict_config[each]:
        table_name=xx['table_name']
        column_filter=xx['column_filter']
        print(table_name, column_filter)
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Thank you